# How to show * symbol againist the mandatory fields in a Activity

Tags: android

I have a requirement to display * symbol against the mandatory fields in a Activity. Can you please suggest how can I accomplish that. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Isn't it possible to use a lable for this?

Comment: just  take a  imageview with * and make it invisible and show it when its required

Comment: Add a Label into your UI, for each field. You can then easily style it red if a field is not properly filled.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have to take Label on that I have to setText as * .

Answer (score 7):

I'd say that * as a marker for a required field does not follow native Android theme. A combination of `setHint` and `setError` would look more natural for an Android app.

Comment: Thanks Denis for your reply . I have done above requirement by taking Label on that I have to set Text as * . Can you please tell me How to set the alignment. Now the * is coming but it is coming horizontally I want * left side but little top of the Edit Text. Can you please tell me the syntax to use setHint and setError.

Answer (score 3):

Just take a Relative Layout and on the Right side of the EditText set the ImageView with * image source like this,

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout 
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent">

  <EditText android:id="@+id/edit_text" 
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:padding="5dip"
  android:text="Hello World"
  />

  <ImageView android:layout_toRightOf="@id/edit_text" 
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_alignTop="@id/edit_text"
  android:src="@drawable/star"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The following should work:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/date"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fontFamily="verdana"
    android:text="FirstName"
    android:textColor="#000"
    android:drawableRight="@drawable/star" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editTextFirstName"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:hint="FirstName" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not to try something like below

```
txt.setText(Html.fromHtml("mm<sup>2</sup>"));
```