# How To Design small Dot to the right of TextView in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, button, textview

[image]

How to achieve these UI in Native Android, I tried drawableRight in TextView with circle Drawable,But I can't get the exact result.

Comment: using a horizontal Linear Layout with TextView and ImageView is no option?

Comment: I found this. Check if it works https://stackoverflow.com/a/7792631/4957929

Comment: Can you minimum working code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the  layout

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp">`enter code here`


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/img_notification"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:text="SORT"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_bell"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_notification_count"
                android:layout_width="8dp"
                android:layout_height="8dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
                android:background="@drawable/background_rounded_bottom_count"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:visibility="visible"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/img_notification"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/img_notification" /> </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

XML drawable:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval">
    <solid android:color="@color/colorPrimary" />
</shape>
```

Answer (score 3):

With **LinearLayout**:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="top"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="SORT"/>
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="10dp"
        android:layout_height="10dp"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Result:
[image]

Add Paddings or Margins as you want ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try this code to design same view

**main_activity.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Hello Text"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textSize="18sp"/>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="10dp"
            android:layout_height="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/pink_circle"
            android:paddingLeft="2dp"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**pink_circle.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
    android:shape="oval" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<solid
    android:color="#F04B82"/>
</shape>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
**layout_file.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_dot"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img_circle"
        android:layout_width="12dp"
        android:layout_height="12dp"
        android:src="@drawable/circle_draw"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/txt_dot"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/txt_dot" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**circle_draw.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval">
    <solid android:color="#F04B82" />

</shape>
```